# Get variable issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

code:

```
import pygame, sys

x = 640
y = 480
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([x,y], pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.OPENGL)

while True:
    x, y = pygame.Surface.get_size()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or event.type == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mendel/My programs/game Project/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    x, y = pygame.Surface.get_size()
TypeError: descriptor 'get_size' of 'pygame.Surface' object needs an argument
```

When I look up the docs it says that i should have no error

Comment: Where do you look up the docs that say that?

Comment: Also, can you explain what your code is supposed to do? Because the more I read it, the less I understand what you were trying to accomplish, which makes it very hard to tell you how to accomplish it…

Comment: @abarnert Here is the link to the docs for that function: http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_size

Comment: @Haz: But that doesn't tell anyone else who knows how to read Python documentation, that his code should work. (It's not a `classmethod`, and it explicitly refers to "the Surface", which pretty strongly implies that there must be an instance of `Surface` in the `self`…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `screen` object instead:

```
x, y = screen.get_size()
```

According to docs, it returns a Surface object

```
pygame.display.set_mode()
Initialize a window or screen for display
set_mode(resolution=(0,0), flags=0, depth=0) -> Surface
```

Comment: `screen` is the result of calling `pygame.display.set_mode()`, which I'm pretty sure is not a `Surface` or anything else with a `get_size` method.

Comment: @abarnert see my updated answer, it returns a `Surface` object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a regular instance method on a class, you have to call it on an *instance* of that class.*

So, how do you get an instance of a class? Well, in general, you either construct an instance by doing something like `my_instance = MyClass(my_params)`, or you call some helper function that does it for you.

For specifics related to `pygame`… you really need to work through a `pygame` tutorial. A surface can be anything from the main "drawing canvas" for your screen or window to an image you loaded. It's not clear what surface you're trying to use here, so I can't tell you how to get one.

You might want to start with [A Newbie Guide to pygame](http://pygame.org/docs/tut/newbieguide.html), and then go on to the [official tutorials](http://pygame.org/docs/).

---

* This isn't quite true. You *can* call a method on a class instead of an instance, but then you have to pass an instance explicitly as the first (`self`) parameter, and you very rarely want to do this. At any rate, that's why you get the somewhat-misleading error message saying that it "needs an argument".

Answer (score -1):

Your syntax is wrong; you are calling get_size on Surface, not a variable.Your code should look like this:

```
variable = pygame.Surface(variable.get_size())
```

so you would call this on your screen variable. The way I formatted this was if your variable is a pygame variable but not Surface (just like your screen variable). To look at how you format the code slightly differently depending on your variable , please look at [pygame's examples](http://nullege.com/codes/search?cq=pygame.Surface.get_size)

Comment: I don't think he wants to construct a new `Surface` the size of his screen every time through the event loop. (Unfortunately, I have no idea what he _does_ want to do… This was a valiant attempt at a guess, but I don't think it's right, and I don't think we have nearly enough information to have much chance of getting anything right.)

Comment: I do agree, we have no idea of knowing what he is using this for. I had a feeling that he scraped his code to give us where the error was, so I just gave him the correct syntax. On the topic of getting a new size every time through the loop, unless the size is supposed to change throughout the game, pulling this `Surface` out of the loop would be much more efficient

Comment: Well, it's the current syntax for _something_, but it's not the correct syntax for calling the `get_size` method on a `Surface` instance… which is a pretty common thing to do, and a much more reasonable thing to do in an event loop. And it seems likely to be closer to what he thought the docs told him he could do. Anyway, if he ever comes back, he can tell us what he intended; if not, we can close the question…